# aws: what does check-dns-availability do?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In documentation you may read:

> Checks if the specified CNAME is available

If I run the command with an already used name:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk check-dns-availability --cname-prefix already_used_name
```

it returns  **"Available": true** which makes me assume it only checks if the name is following the naming convention. Is that true? I think the word **available** in the documentation is misleading.

Comment: What about `FullyQualifiedCNAME` in the response?  Does it **exactly** match the domain of your "already used name?"  Or are you getting back a response that is from a region other than the one where that name is already in use?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the FullyQualifiedCNAME matches **exactly**  my domain. I didn't put the region and profile parameters in my example to simplify it.

Comment: Perhaps it's returning true because it's already reserved by your account, rather than someone else's?  Sorry for the mere speculation, but I have no EB running to test this against, and the docs for the [underlying API call](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_CheckDNSAvailability.html) don't imply that it's only a validity check.  If you are willing to mention the domain, I can test whether I see true or false for the same request, which might reveal useful info.

Comment: I made multiple tests with random cname and it never returned "false". Instead, it returned an error when the naming convention was not matched. Don't know if that qualifies as an answer.

Comment: I think we need to test it with known values across account boundaries before we have a full answer.  I'll see if I can find some EB running somewhere and test its name within the same account and across account boundaries.